# Creating Directories from .txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to write something in Python 2.7 to create many directories from a .txt file. So far I got this:

```html
import os

path = '.'

system_name = open('systems.txt')
system = system_name.readline()
while system: 
 print(system)
 for system in system:
  os.mkdir(os.path.join(path,(system)))
 
system_name.close()
```

My input file looks like this:

BaO_Fm-3m_26961_RPBE

BaZrO3_Pm-3m_90049_RPBE

BeO_P63mc_61181_RPBE

Bi2O3_P211c_15072_RPBE

CaMgSi2O6_C12c1_30522_RPBE

...

The problem is that I get many folders but all of them are created letter by letter from the first line and not row by row like I intended.

Than you very much for the kind help and enjoy your day,

Ingo

Comment: If you have a Unix-like shell: `xargs mkdir < systems.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`readline()` reads one line. Then you iterate over that line using `for system in system`, so you get each character in turn.

Conveniently, files in Python can already be iterated over line by line:

```
system_name = open('systems.txt')
for system in system_name:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, system))
system_name.close()
```

You could also look into the `with` construct to make this exception-safe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're iterating over a first line instead of list of lines so you create folders for each character from the first line. Use `readlines` instead.

```
with open('systems.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for file_name in lines:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, file_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to open files with the **with** statement for more safety. Also, you can iterate on a file with a for loop, which will give you all the lines.

```
with open('systems.txt') as system_name:
    for line in system_name:
        print(line)
        line = line.strip() #to remove things like '\n'
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, line))
```

Comment: Cheers mate,

that was really bothering me so much as well:

line = line.strip() #to remove things like '\n'

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

path = '.'

lines = tuple(open('systems.txt', 'r'))
print lines
for system in lines:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path,(system)))
```